# Problem sorting list using SwiftData and returning the right item to delete

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I have a tripDetailView that is passed a model

```
var trip: TripSummariesSD
```

That I sort

```
let sortedTrip = trip.toTripJournal?.sorted { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp}
```

Then I list

```
List {
  //ForEach(trip.toTripJournal!, id: \.self) { detail in
  ForEach(sortedTrip!, id: \.self) { detail in
  Text("\(formatDateStampA(detail.timestamp)) \(detail.latitude), \(detail.longitude) \(formatMPH(convertMPStoMPH(detail.speed))) mph")
  }
  .onDelete(perform: deleteTripJournalEntry)
}

private func deleteTripJournalEntry(at offsets: IndexSet) {
  offsets.forEach { index in
            
    print("index: \(index)"
    print("item :  \(trip.toTripJournal![index].timestamp)")
                        
    tripJournalEntryToDelete = trip.toTripJournal![index]
    showDeleteConfirmation = true
    }
}
```

If I run as shown my list is not sorted but when I select an entry to delete it does return the right index and item.  But if I swap to my sortedTrip  I show a properly sorted list and get the right index but wrong item.  I would like to show the list sorted and have it select the right item.  It looks like between the data and the list I can't get them to sync up.

FYI, I did load the toTripJournal information into SwiftData in sorted date order but when I bring it up here the items at the data level appear to be at random.

A sorted list that returns the correct item to delete in SwiftData

Comment: Isn't is just the matter of using `@Query` to set the array to list?

Comment: If you use sortedTrip in the List then you need to use sortedTrip in deleteTripJournalEntry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this approach, finding the trip to delete in the sorted array (when using `ForEach(sortedTrip!, id: \.self)...`), and finding the equivalent trip `index` (based on `id` or some other unique feature) in the trip.toTripJournal array. Then you can use that index to locate the `trip` to delete.

Example code:

```
func deleteTripJournalEntry(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    offsets.forEach { index in
        
        print("index: \(index)")
        print("item : \(trip.toTripJournal![index].timestamp)")
        
        // get the trip from the sortedTrip array
        let trip = sortedTrip[index]
        
        // find the index of that trip in the trip.toTripJournal array, based on id
        if let jIndex = trip.toTripJournal.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == trip.id}) {
            tripJournalEntryToDelete = trip.toTripJournal![jIndex] // <--- here
            showDeleteConfirmation = true
            // do deletions here
            // sortedTrip.remove(at: index)
            // context delete
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftData models are always classes so you already have the right object at `let trip = sortedTrip[index]`, the rest of the code is irrelevant.